# Something like .dll on Linux - how to get them?

Tags: c++, linux, dll, compilation, gtkmm

I have program using gtkmm, gtkglextmm and exiv2.

I want to include these libraries with the executable, because the app will not work if user doesn't has them on his/her system. On Windows .dll files solved the matter (I put them in the same directory as output file).

How to attached similar libraries on Linux? Is there any tool helping with that? I cannot force user to install dependencies.

Comment: On Linux, the equivalent of a .dll is a "dynamic shared object", or a .so.  You could statically link the required libraries in your executable, but that is really not best practice.  See David Heffernan's answer.  You do not need to force the user to install the dependencies; you simply tell the user that it is their choice and they cannot run your application without those dependencies.

Comment: If your program is free software (e.g. GPL or LGPL licensed) you'll probably get help to package it within major distributions (and sometimes even, some nice person package it for you).

Comment: William I have read somewhere that You can't do static linking with gtk (and gtkmm). I wonder if it is true... Also, as I've written below David Heffernan' answer - I need to make this program working even if user is too lazy to install dependencies by himself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better yet, use the package system of the distribution[s] you want to target, e.g. [.deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_package) packaging on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint (with `aptitude` or `apt-get`, themselves using `dpkg`), Yum/Rpm on Redhat/Fedora, etc etc.

DLL-s are called [shared libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_library#Shared_libraries) (files named `*.so`) on Linux (in [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format, use `objdump`, `nm` ... to explore them, and `gcc -fPIC -shared` to build them). They can be programmatically loaded with [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) & `dlsym`. Beware that there are important differences between windows DLL-s & Linux *.so ([dynamic linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) don't have the same meaning on Windows & Linux)

Answer (score 14):

Standard practice on Linux is not to redistribute your dependencies. Doing so just creates large amounts of duplication. You should instead specify the dependencies in your installation package and let the package manager resolve them.

Comment: Well I NEED to get my program working on Linux and someone is to lazy to install dependencies. I know what is the standard practicebut I need to get this done like with dlls on Windows.

Comment: This is not Windows. It is trivial to install the packages with your preferred package manager. That simply is the way to do it. Don't fight the platform.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Let's say I have a custom standalone platform. (Like a custom build of LFS for embedded devices.) How would you package the application then?

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple sh script to start your program:

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/intall/directory
path/to/your/exe
```

and put so libraries to /path/to/intall/directory

Comment: That don't solve the dependency issues (details vary with distributions), and I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: Why? ABI of basic things like glibc changed seldom, as things like X11 protocol. So if have other "so" libraries with your app, you can run it without problems. Now imagine situation, when you use something like qt 4.6, and you need show how you application looks like to user. But user have only ancient debian machine. What do you do, update all system to run your application once?

Comment: Yes, because Qt has so much dependencies that it is not worth solving them manually. If needed, run a "new" system in a chroot-ed environment -but even that won't work with an ancient kernel and a recent libc

Comment: Who told to do it manually? You can use "ldd" any script language to gather all dependicies.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be simpler (in the general case) than depending upon a package manager provided by the distribution.

Comment: For example, openoffice and matlab binary packages contains all ".so" library that they require.